# Cherry-pick branches from one Repo to another

Tags: github, merge, gitlab, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I have two repositories Repo1 and Repo2. I have few new branches in Repo1 that should be moved to Repo2. How can I `cherry-pick` those branches(along with all the commits in it) and move it to second repo?

So far I have done:

```
git remote add repo2 https://...repo1.git  
git fetch other
```

It listed out all the branches created in Repo1. But I'm not sure how can I cherry-pick those branches and push in Repo2.

Ps. I cannot do `git remote` since it will cause alot of conflicts as there's some difference in data in both the repositories.

Answer (score 1):

First, you fetch not be should be `git fetch other` but.

```
cd /path/to/repo2
git remote add repo1 https://...repo1.git  
git fetch repo1
```

In other words, you would work in a local clone of the target repo (repo2), not in repo1.

Second, it should list *all* branches, with `git branch -avv`.
However, since repo1 and 2 have no common history, it would be up to you to determine the start of a repo1 branch (or it would consider the branch commits all the way back to the first repo1 commit: there is no common branch from which said branch has started in repo1)

If you think a repo1 branch can be applied to an existing repo2 history, you can:

- create a new branch branch from `repo1/aBranchToMove`
- `rebase --onto` the repo1 branch (on)to an existing repo2 branch

That is:

```
cd /path/to/repo2
git switch -c newBranch repo1/branch
git rebase --onto main <first-Commit>~ newBranch
```

That will relocate commits, from `<first-Commit>` (that you need to lookup in repo1) up to newBranch (which references the repo1 branch HEAD, that you want to cherry-pick) onto an existing repo2 branch (here '`main`' for instance)

Comment: I can't use git rebase due to some code conflicts and different heads. I needed only cherrypick. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: @PrachiSharma The rebase will only automate the manual cherry-picking you will end up using. Said cherry-picking would involve the same kind of conflict.